# Fail test in VSC using Robot Framework

Tags: visual-studio-code, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

Learning RobotFramework using VSC.

Got downloaded chromedriver_win32.zip for Chrome 98 from here::
https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=98.0.4758.80/

When I run my 1st test in VSC I get fail and the message shows:
This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 93
Current browser version is 98.0.4758.82 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

Why it says Chrome version 93 when it's 98?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace that chromedriver.exe by the one you have downloaded and extracted.

You need to know where that executable is (being found from the PATH environment variable).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, @Helio :) It's sorted now.